# iOS 9 Swipe don't call editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9

I made a tableview with editActionsForRowAtIndexPath functionality and I want to show de delete button when I swipe. However the row is not showing a button. I thought maybe there is something that block the swipe gesture but when I set 'setEditing' to true I can swipe the button away. Maybe you can help me to solve the problem or a way to get the problem.

See below for my code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    print("editActionsForRowAtIndexPath")
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Verwijder") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in


    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.35, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
    return [deleteAction]
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // All tasks are handled by blocks defined in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath, however iOS8 requires this method to enable editing
}
```